# Search not finding Entries of certain status on an iphone

Tags: search, mobile

I'm using Simple Search with the following code.

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="product" search_in="everywhere" status="open|sold|On Hold" result_page="/search" form_class="form-search pull-right"}
```

It works as expected except on an iPhone. On an iphone, if the product being searched has a status of "sold" I get a no results page. This behavior is only on iPhones. Tablets, iPads, laptops and desktops all work for "open", "sold" and "on hold" products. On an iphone searches work for "open" and "on hold" itemsS

Comment: Suspect caching issue.  Cache could be on Phone or upstream in network proxy cache.  Could you update your question: have you tried more than one iPhone?  Have you tried more than one network?

Comment: That was my first suspect so yes, tried on different iphones and networks. Just really odd. @AllInOne